# ¿Cómo Consumir webservices API REST CON PHP De Varias fuentes?

Tags: php, json, webservice

Quisiera saber como consumir webservices con `PHP`.
Mi idea es inicialmente el Archivo `PHP` Consulte una lista de `webservices` y los resultados almacenarlos en un `dataset` el cual pueda manejar(ORDENAR, FILTRAR).

Es decir por ejemplo:
Tengo los Webservice: WS1, WS2, WS3.
Entro a mi web y esta consume WS1, WS2 y WS3 obtiene los `json` response(Respuestas en formato `JSON`). Las une en un solo `JSON`, el cual ordeno por nombre y muestro en formato `HTML/PHP` en mi web.

===========================================================================
Good afternoon to know how to consume webservices with `PHP`.
My idea is the `PHP` file Consult a list of web services and the results in a set of data that are manageable (ORDER, FILTER).

That is, for example:
I have the web services: WS1, WS2, WS3.
I enter my web and this consumes WS1, WS2 and WS3 gets the answer json (Answers in `JSON` format). It joins them in a single `JSON`, which I sort by name and show in `HTML / PHP` format on my website.

```
<?php
class CurlRequest
{
    private function getWS1($parm1,$param2,$param3)
    {
        $data = array(
            "where1" => $parm1,
            "where2" => $parm2,
            "where3" => $parm3
        );
        $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/webservices/test_ejemplos/ws1.php");
        /*
        El retorno es un array con objetos de tipo:
        Object hotel{
            "id" => "123",
            "name" => "Hotel Estelar de Miraflores",
            "address" => "Av. Benavides cruce con Av. Larco",
            "stars" => "5",
            "status" => "enabled"
        }
        */
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if(!$response) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return $response;
        }
    }

    private function getWS2($parm1,$param2,$param3)
    {
        $data = array(
            "where1" => $parm1,
            "where2" => $parm2,
            "where3" => $parm3
        );
        $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/webservices/test_ejemplos/ws2.php");
        /*
        El retorno es un array con objetos de tipo:
        Object hotel{
            "id" => "123",
            "name" => "Hotel Marriot Premium",
            "address" => "Av. Larco, frente a larcomar",
            "stars" => "5",
            "status" => "enabled"
        }
        */
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if(!$response) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return $response;
        }
    }

    public function hacerBusqueda($parm1,$param2,$param3)
    {
        $response1 = getWS1($parm1,$param2,$param3);
        $response2 = getWS2($parm1,$param2,$param3);
        /* AQUI NECESITO UNIR AMBOS ARRAY DE OBJETOS */
        /* LUEGO NECESITO PODER ORDENAR DICHO ARRAY POR hotel.name */
        /* FINALMENTE RECORRER EL ARRAY E IMPRIMIR CON ECHO CON UN FORMATO HTML */
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes algo de código que podamos ver de como lo estas realizando?

Comment: Si, lo acabo de añadir

Answer (score 1):

Bueno por fin pude hacerlo. Dejo la clase.

```
<?php
class CurlRequest
{
    private function getWS1($param1,$param2,$param3)
    {
        $data = array(
            "where1" => $param1,
            "where2" => $param2,
            "where3" => $param3
        );
        $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/webservices/hotel/ws1.php");
        /*
        El retorno es un array con objetos de tipo:
        Object hotel{
            "id" => "123",
            "name" => "Hotel Estelar de Miraflores",
            "address" => "Av. Benavides cruce con Av. Larco",
            "stars" => "5",
            "status" => "enabled"
        }
        */
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if(!$response) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return $response;
        }
    }

    private function getWS2($param1,$param2,$param3)
    {
        $data = array(
            "where1" => $param1,
            "where2" => $param2,
            "where3" => $param3
        );
        $ch = curl_init("http://localhost/webservices/hotel/ws2.php");
        /*
        El retorno es un array con objetos de tipo:
        Object hotel{
            "id" => "123",
            "name" => "Hotel Marriot Premium",
            "address" => "Av. Larco, frente a larcomar",
            "stars" => "5",
            "status" => "enabled"
        }
        */
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($data));
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        if(!$response) {
            return false;
        }else{
            return $response;
        }
    }

    public function hacerBusqueda($parm1,$param2,$param3)
    {
        $response1 = json_decode($this->getWS1($parm1,$param2,$param3));
        $response2 = json_decode($this->getWS2($parm1,$param2,$param3));
        /* AQUI NECESITO UNIR AMBOS ARRAY DE OBJETOS */
        $resultado = array_merge($response1, $response2);
        /* LUEGO NECESITO PODER ORDENAR DICHO ARRAY POR hotel.name */
        function cmp($a, $b)
        {
            return strcmp($a->codigo, $b->codigo);
        }
        usort($resultado, "cmp");
        /* FINALMENTE RECORRER EL ARRAY E IMPRIMIR CON ECHO CON UN FORMATO HTML */
        foreach ($resultado as &$valor) {
            echo $valor->codigo."<br>";
        }
        unset($valor);
    }
}
```